# Pyodbc connecting to Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database with Pyodbc:

```
pyodbc.connect('{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=serverxzy.com:1234;Uid=myusername;Pwd=pass123')
```

I get the following error message:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any suggestions how to fix it would be appreciated. I'm specifically interested in getting pyodbc to work and NOT cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the proprietary library for Oracle, cx_Oracle, and you must have the Oracle client and SDK installed.

Once this is all set up you can simply:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = 'USER/PASS@HOSTNAME:PORT/ALIAS'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
```

Then you can create a cursor with the conn object:

```
c = conn.cursor()
```

And then you can execute SQL:

```
c.execute(SQL)
```

Comment: If it was that simple I wouldn't have tried to switch from cx_Oracle to pyodbc. But maybe you can answer my other question in that case:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845401/cx-oracle-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-fo

Comment: 0

Please install according to Instant Client 12.1 requirement from https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

the required Visual Studio VS 2010 redistributable libraries for VS2010 SP1 and C++

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

and bounce machine

Answer (score 1):

Consider specifying the `DRIVER` in [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/):

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=serverxzy.com:1234;
                Uid=myusername;Pwd=pass123')
```

Comment: This has no impact

Comment: Same exact error? Check if Oracle driver is aligned to bit version of Python? ODBC drivers/DSNs can be found in ODBCcad32.exe in both: C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Also, I use [pypyodbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463591/does-pyodbc-have-any-design-advantages-over-pypyodbc).